# Is the apply function recursive?

Tags: scala

Consider following trait definition:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {

  def cons[A](hd: => A, t1: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = t1
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

}
```

Because `apply` expect `varargs` as argument I can create a new `Stream` like:

```
val s = Stream(2,3,4,5)
```

I have few questions about `ADT` `Stream`

1. Do the `apply` function a recursive call? I tried to debug the code,
   but it goes only once through.
2. When I have a definition `val s = Stream(2,3,4,5)`, how can I call
       the head of it? I tried `s.h` but I've got compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's recursive, since it calls `apply` on the tail of `as`. However since `h` and `t` in Cons are functions that are only evaluated on demand, you entered the method only once in the debugger, because the tail was not yet evaluated.

You can get the head of the `s` with pattern matching

```
val h = s match {
  case Cons(h,t) => h
}
```

The type of h is `() => Integer` so to get the integer you have to evaluate it.

```
h()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Stream` is an implementation of lazy collections: its head and tail are evaluated only once it is called upon.

This is why the properties of `Cons` are of type `() => T`, ie functions of zero elements.

The `apply` function defines its head as the first element of the `varargs`, and its tail as the same function applied to the tail of the `varags`. However, since they are evaluated only on demand, your call on `apply(1, 2, 3)` does not call the tail function, so you do not see the recursive calls.

Since arguments of `Cons` are zero-argument functions, you need to call them to get their value. So to get the head of your `Stream`, juste invoke `s.h()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking only on apply method signature one could think that we are dealing here with regular recursion:

```
def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
  if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
```

Let analyze cons signature:

```
def cons[A](hd: => A, t1: => Stream[A]): Stream[A]
```

As you can see both parameters are "call-by-name". This mean that expression passed are not evaluated immediatly. Under the hood scala compiler expands them to function without arguments. This function can be invoked in arbitrary place in a program.

Regarding cons method, consider those two lines:

```
lazy val head = hd
lazy val tail = t1
```

No evaluation is performed here either.
Let's just assume we don't perform memoization, this way we can substitue cons arguments explicitly to Cons constructor invocation, this leads to the following:

```
Cons(h: () => hd, t: () => t1)
```

Now thanks to the nature of "call-by-name" we can write:

```
Cons(h: () => as.head, t: () => apply(as.tail:_*))
```

The following is not a valid scala code but explains what is happening. Now it is clear that recursive call to apply method is performed only if someone explicitly calls `t()` function on `Cons` instance.
There are many benefits of this approach, the bigest one being that we avoid stack-overflow. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes, because of the tail recursion.

Comment: `apply` method is not tail recursive. It uses common pattern of lifting recursive call into the heap but definitly do not use tail recursion.

Comment: What does it mean lifting recursive?

Comment: Well i mean techniques allowing to avoid stackoverflow errors when dealing with recursive-calls. One of them is lifting recursive call in anonymous function, and invoking the latter outside of the current invocation stack frame. This is extactly what is happing in your code. Other method is using futures: `def recFun(x: Int) = Future(x + recFun(2 * x))`